# PowerApps Template - How to edit collections?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps

Hello Stack Community!

I'm currently in the process of adopting the Leave Request template for use in my organization. However, I've run into a few problems. I'm attempting to edit the already established collections in the app and am having a lot of trouble doing so. I've read the Patch article and I just can't figure out how to successfully use the Patch function to update the various collections I will need.
Some methods I've tried include editing the OnStart action in the Login Screen and this didn't work. I figured out how to edit the Company Holidays Collection via Excel on OneDrive. Essentially, I just need to edit one collection, the LeaveTypeCollection. I want to edit the options as well as the image (icon) available.

Can someone please give me a step-by-step guide on how to do so? I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2):

To update the LeaveTypeCollection, you can click on the Login Screen and then select the OnStart property in the formula dropdown and then expand the formula bar. You should be able to edit the values that you want to change or add a new leave type to the collection. You can then save and reopen the app and you should see the new leave types show up in the preview of an app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information Emily. I remember I tried editing the "OnStart" function on the LoginScreen and the changes didn't reflect immediately. I guess it takes some time for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I had to save, close, and reopen the app to see the changes appear!